# What's the exact equivalent of python's native hash() function in Java?

Tags: java, python, hash-function

I am trying to convert a Python script I wrote to Java. In the script I am using python's native hash() function on strings. I need to find the exact equivalent of this in Java to avoid discrepancies. Thanks in advance!

Comment: And what does python's function do, exactly?

Comment: Every object in Java implements [hashCode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()), I think that is the equivalent, given that for custom objects the [hash](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hash) function calls the implementation `__hash__`

Comment: From [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__) :By default, the `__hash__()` values of str and bytes objects are “salted” with an unpredictable random value. Although they remain constant within an individual Python process, they are not predictable between repeated invocations of Python. This is intended to provide protection against a denial-of-service caused by carefully-chosen inputs that exploit the worst case performance of a dict insertion, O(n^2) complexity. See http://www.ocert.org/advisories/ocert-2011-003.html for details.

Comment: Sounds like there is no "exact equivalent" unless you write it yourself. The string hashCode from standard Java library does not include a random salt.

Comment: Both hashCode and `__hash__` has the same contract, if both objects are equal the hash is equal

Answer (score 1):

The Python method [`hash(object)`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/hash)

> calls `__hash__()` method of an object which are set by default for any object.

---

The exact equivalent in Java to that is [`Objects.hashCode(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html#hashCode(java.lang.Object)) that calls `hashCode()` on the given object and returns the result.

---

The equivalence is given by the syntax. It may **not** be given by the underlying hashing algorithm.